# Elevation mapping

Tags: ros, hector-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04 and I am looking for elavation mapping packages in order to get a elevation map.

I found two packages:

ETH Zurich:
https://github.com/ethz-asl/elevation_mapping

Hector: hector_elevation_maping:
https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation

I have tried the ethz package but I have a core error when I launch the node, and now I am trying the hector elevation mapping package, but I do not find too much documentation about it.

Has anyone any experience working with elevation maps? Any suggestion about the best package to use and any sort of documentation would be grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Teresa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236513/elevation-mapping/) by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Teresa,
We have just updated our [elevation_mapping package](https://github.com/ethz-asl/elevation_mapping). Could you please let me know if you have any issues with this version?
Best, Peter

---

Originally posted by [Péter Fankhauser](https://answers.ros.org/users/20024/p%C3%A9ter-fankhauser/) with karma: 18 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on 2016-09-19**:
Hi Peter,
I did tried your elevation mapping package, however the elevation_mapping node died as soon as I run the simple_demo.launch file. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on 2016-09-19**:
Hi,
I am using the last version of the elevation packing that Peter updated and it works for me. I had the same problem as you before the update. Are you using the last version?

**Comment by [rahul puram](https://answers.ros.org/users/40484/rahul-puram/) on 2020-08-23**:
Hi tseco, are you able to map using that package in gazebo? Thanks